# How to loop MongoDB collection and process doc one by one?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to loop a MongoDB collection and processing each document one by one. If the document matches a specific condition, I'll update the document to mark it "processed," and insert or update another collection based on the document.

Here's my code but it's not working:

```
db.Chapter2.find( {} ).forEach(function(doc) {    
    var processed = true;
    if (doc._id = ObjectId("5a57c993d9dd9a41ead05a12")) {
      db.Chapter2.update( { _id: doc._id }, { $set: { "processed": processed } } ); 
      count = db.authors.find({ "Author": doc.Author });
      if ( count == 0) {
        db.authors.insertOne({Author: doc.Author, count: 1});
      } else {
        db.authors.updateOne({Author: doc.Author, {$set: {count: count +1}});
      }
    }
})
```

Please note:
I am not looking for aggregate resolution.

Thanks in advance.

Richard Xu

Comment: Why are you hardcoding an ObjectId for the docs you are processing instead of using the id of the doc itself?

Answer (score 0):

First of all your code has a mistake in the condition, it should be `==` not `=`.

As far as processing 1 doc at a time, I suggest using [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) library for such needs.

Here is a sample of how to convert your code into using async library

```
const async = require('async')
db.Chapter2.find({}, function(err, docs) {
    // docs is a collection of all of our documents, now we can use async.forEach to loop through them
    async.forEach(docs, function(doc, callback) {
        var processed = true;

        // doc is our current item in this collection, everytime we are done with it we would use callback so our loop moves on

        // Since you already have the doc on hand there is no need to call `update` you can just alter values and call `save`
        doc.processed = processed 

        // I suggest Author is an index in this collection to optimize it
        count = db.authors.find({ "Author": doc.Author });

        if ( count == 0) {
              db.authors.insertOne({Author: doc.Author, count: 1});
        } else {
              db.authors.updateOne({Author: doc.Author, {$set: {count: count +1}});
        }
        doc.save(function(err) {
           // In order for us to move to the next item we need to callback
           // the first argument is an error so here we simply check
           // If there is an error then callback with error otherwise without
           err ? callback(err) : callback(null)
        })

    }, function(err){
        // The loop is completed
        if (err) {
           // But there was an error handle it here
        } else {
           // The loop completed successfully
        }
    })
})
```

This answer can be optimized much further. But this should do the trick to your question

**EDIT: I am not sure why do you have `var processed = true` if this value is never changing. Mind as well just set `doc.processed = true`**